# How to prevent NC_CALCSIZE from resizing my form? C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a custom form (C#/Windows Forms/Vista/Windows7), and overriding WndProc to capture WM_NCPAINT, WM_NCCALCSIZE and WM_NCHITTEST to draw a custom frame. I'm almost done with it but there is a problem that I could not work around myself.

The problem is that NC_CALCSIZE makes my form shrink when I restore it after its maximized. I´ve googled it and found an answer from Bob Powell, and he stated that I neednt to handle NC_CALCSIZE when WPARAM is TRUE. After I've done that, WM_NCPAINT had no effect anymore (it does handle the WM_NCPAINT, but it does not paint the non-client area anymore, only after I invalidate it).

So, resuming, when I handle WM_NCCALCSIZE(WPARAM == TRUE) it shrinks my form, when I dont, it doesnt paint anymore.

Has anyone had this problem before? If more code is needed I can provide it.
Tks.

Here's my WN_CALCSIZE code:

```
private void WndProcNonClientCalcSize(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.WParam == WinAPI.FALSE)
        {
            this.Log(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), "FALSE");

            WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS csp;
            csp = (WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS));
            csp.rectProposed.Top += this._nonClientHeight;
            csp.rectProposed.Bottom -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            csp.rectProposed.Left += this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            csp.rectProposed.Right -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(csp, m.LParam, false);
        }
        else if (m.WParam == WinAPI.TRUE)
        {
            this.Log(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), "TRUE");

            WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS csp;
            csp = (WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS));
            csp.rectProposed.Top += this._nonClientHeight;
            csp.rectProposed.Bottom -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            csp.rectProposed.Left += this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            csp.rectProposed.Right -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(csp, m.LParam, false);
        }

        m.Result = WinAPI.TRUE;
    }
```

Here's my WM_NCPAINT code:

```
private bool WndProcNonClientPaint(ref Message m)
    {
        this.Log(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), string.Empty);

        this.PaintNonClient(m.HWnd, (IntPtr)m.WParam);
        m.Result = WinAPI.TRUE;
        return true;
    }

    private void PaintNonClient(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn)
    {
        WinAPI.RECT windowRect = new WinAPI.RECT();
        WinAPI.GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref windowRect);

        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0,
            windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left,
            windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top);

        if (bounds.Width == 0 || bounds.Height == 0)
            return;

        Region clipRegion = new Region(bounds);

        if (hRgn != (IntPtr)1)
            clipRegion = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);

        WinAPI.DCV dcv =
                WinAPI.DCV.WINDOW |
                WinAPI.DCV.INTERSECTRGN |
                WinAPI.DCV.CACHE |
                WinAPI.DCV.CLIPSIBLINGS;

        IntPtr hDC =
            WinAPI.GetDCEx(
                hWnd,
                hRgn,
                dcv);

        if (hDC == IntPtr.Zero)
            hDC = WinAPI.GetWindowDC(hWnd);

        IntPtr compatiblehDC = WinAPI.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        IntPtr compatibleBitmap = WinAPI.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        try
        {
            WinAPI.SelectObject(compatiblehDC, compatibleBitmap);
            WinAPI.BitBlt(compatiblehDC, 0, 0, bounds.Width, bounds.Height, hDC, 0, 0, WinAPI.SRCCOPY);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(compatiblehDC))
            {
                Rectangle outterEdge = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

                int x = this._nonClientBorderThickness;
                int y = this._nonClientHeight;
                int width = this.Width - (this._nonClientBorderThickness * 2);
                int height = this.Height - this._nonClientBorderThickness - this._nonClientHeight;

                Rectangle innerEdge = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

                GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

                path.AddRectangle(outterEdge);
                path.AddRectangle(innerEdge);

                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 48)))
                    g.FillPath(brush, path);

                path.Dispose();
            }

            WinAPI.BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, bounds.Width, bounds.Height, compatiblehDC, 0, 0, WinAPI.SRCCOPY);
        }
        finally
        {
            WinAPI.DeleteObject(compatibleBitmap);
            WinAPI.DeleteDC(compatiblehDC);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not handling the FALSE case property.  That gives you a RECT (not a NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS) that contains the size of the frame.  You must modify it and make it *smaller* to indicate what part of the frame is the client area.

Comment: It seems the FALSE case is not the problem, since its when I modify the TRUE case that i get the problem of not getting things properly drawn. Either way I did change the false case to this, but nothing change:

WinAPI.RECT rect = (WinAPI.RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WinAPI.RECT));
                rect.Left += this._nonClientBorderThickness;
                rect.Top += this._nonClientHeight;
                rect.Right -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
                rect.Bottom -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, false);

Comment: You are returning TRUE from WM_NCCALCSIZE, but you are supposed to return some flags. I think you want WVR_HREDRAW | WVR_VREDRAW so that the repaint occurs.

Comment: @Tergiver, I've tried this as well, but I couldnt get it working =/
It keeps shrinking my form or it doesnt paint correctly.
Anyone have an axample??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I couldnt get it to work, it seems the return WM_NCCALCSIZE is more complex than I expected. I simply couldnt understand it, as it didnt do what i expected it to do. I tried to do what this article says but again it was no use:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/15/54925.aspx

So i googled again and I found this article on CodeProject, describing the same problem I had:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55180/Extending-the-Non-Client-Area-in-Aero

The work around was to listen to WM_SYSCOMMAND and capture SC_RESTORE, setting my form width and height as I Maximized/Restored.

My WM_NCCALCSIZE became this:

```
    private void WndProcNonClientCalcSize(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.WParam == WinAPI.FALSE)
        {
            this.Log(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), "FALSE");

            WinAPI.RECT rect = (WinAPI.RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WinAPI.RECT));
            rect.Left += this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            rect.Top += this._nonClientHeight;
            rect.Right -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            rect.Bottom -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, false);

            m.Result = WinAPI.FALSE;
        }
        else if (m.WParam == WinAPI.TRUE)
        {
            this.Log(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), "TRUE");

            WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS csp;
            csp = (WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS));

            WinAPI.RECT rectNewClient = csp.rectProposed;

            rectNewClient.Left += this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            rectNewClient.Top += this._nonClientHeight;
            rectNewClient.Right -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;
            rectNewClient.Bottom -= this._nonClientBorderThickness;

            csp.rectProposed = rectNewClient;
            csp.rectBeforeMove = csp.rectProposed;

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(csp, m.LParam, false);

            m.Result = (IntPtr)(WinAPI.NCCALCSIZE_RESULTS.ValidRects);
        }
    }
```

and my WM_SYSCOMMAND:

```
    private void WndProcSysCommand(ref Message m)
    {
        UInt32 param;
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            param = (UInt32)(m.WParam.ToInt32());
        else
            param = (UInt32)(m.WParam.ToInt64());

        if ((param & 0xFFF0) == (int)WinAPI.SystemCommands.SC_RESTORE)
        {
            this.Height = this._storedHeight;
            this.Width = this._storedWidth;
        }
        else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            this._storedHeight = this.Height;
            this._storedWidth = this.Width;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

It might not be the best solution, but got the work done. If anyone could provide a better solution, I would really apreciate.

Tks, Hans Passant and Tergiver for your attention.

Comment: Just a (small) performance note: You might want to enclose the Height and Width change with `SuspendLayout(); Height=; Width=; ResumeLayout(false)` otherwise if both Width and Height changed, you might get two re-calc-layouts instead of one.

Comment: Also `UInt32 param = m.WParam.ToInt32()` accomplishes the same thing as the IntPtr.Size check, cast to long, cast back to int, without the extra casting.

Answer (score 2):

It's not problem with `WM_NCCALCSIZE`. When processing `WM_NCCALCSISE`, .NET call `RestoreWindowBoundsIfNecessary()` method, so the window's size changed (See [Changing a window's restore position using SetWindowPlacement doesn't work on every window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126041/changing-a-windows-restore-position-using-setwindowplacement-doesnt-work-on-ev)).
You can either manually cache form's size when form is minimized and reset when it's restored, or do not call base `WndProc()` method, which call `RestoreWindowBoundsIfNecessary()`

Answer (score 0):

I have had different results and I'd actually like to get public input on this solution:

```
protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
{
    width += BORDER_LEFT_WIDTH + BORDER_RIGHT_WIDTH;
    height += BORDER_TOP_HEIGHT + TITLEBAR_HEIGHT + BORDER_BOTTOM_HEIGHT;
    base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
}
```

This, in effect, counteracts the shrinkage I was running into while dealing with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem has more elegant solution, though still hackish. See [Custom window frame with DWM: how to handle WM_NCCALCSIZE correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085317/custom-window-frame-with-dwm-how-to-handle-wm-nccalcsize-correctly).

The difference is that solutions here either change window size causing redraw/flickering or artificially shrink bounds, while solution from the post above just say that your window does not have title/border hence size of the window and client area are equal.

By the way, if you want client area to occupy all window size WndProcNonClientCalcSize can be simplified to

```cs
private void WndProcNonClientCalcSize(ref Message m)
{
  m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
}
```