# How to keep border on a fixed form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, window, border

I want my Windows Forms form to keep the window border, while having no title bar and being non-resizable (fixed) (similarly to window previews, when one hovers mouse over button on the taskbar):

[image]

Setting `ControlBox` to `false` and `Text` to `""` removes the title bar and keeps the border as I want to, but the border is visible only if the form is sizeable. When I set the `FormBorderStyle` to one of the `Fixed*` styles, the border disappears:

[image]

How may I achieve the described behavior?

Comment: For my please wait dialog, I just put a panel docked around my form (behind controls) and used the panel border

Comment: "Fixed" is not a valid setting for the FormBorderStyle property.  Document your question better.  Include at least include a screen shot of the running window, the Windows version and a shot of a they way you want it to look.

Comment: @HansPassant People, who answered my question seem to understand perfectly what I am asking about. I included the screenshots, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pinvoke [SetWindowsLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowlong) and adjust [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
// run in LINQpad
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x040000;
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
void Main()
{
    var form = new Form();
    form.ControlBox = false;
    form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    form.Show();
    SetWindowLong(form.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(form.Handle, GWL_STYLE) | WS_SIZEBOX);
}
```

After that you would have to [prevent resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460208/how-to-prevent-nc-calcsize-from-resizing-my-form-c-sharp) manually though.

Comment: Now he's got two problems, these declarations are wrong for 64-bit code.  Overriding the CreateParams property is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I just played around with a project of mine and set `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` through the Design view, and the window seems to keep the border for Windows 8. I initially had text in the title, which was forcing the border to render.  I removed the text and the border no longer rendered, so as a hacky solution I just input an empty string, by hitting backspace a few times.  This made the border show up and remain fixed.