# Custom window frame with DWM: how to handle WM_NCCALCSIZE correctly

Tags: c#, winforms-interop, dwm

I'm trying to make a custom window frame for my form using DWM.
The platform is C# WinForms, Pinvoking DWM.

Following the [MSDN article on making custom window frame with DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the main steps are next:

1. Remove standard frame (non-client area), returning 0 in answer to WM_NCCALCSIZE message
2. Extend the frame into client area using DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea function

I handle WM_NCCALCSIZE message in the next way:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
   switch (m.Msg)
   {
       case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
            if (isDwmWindowFramePaintEnabled() && m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            else
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
            return;
   }
}
```

According to [MSDN documentation on WM_NCCALCSIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> When wParam is TRUE, simply returning 0 without processing the
> NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS rectangles will cause the client area to resize to
> the size of the window, including the window frame. This will remove
> the window frame and caption items from your window, leaving only the
> client area displayed.

Everything is fine and works for me except one issue.
When I maximize/restore window, it's always growing a little bit when it gets restored.
I think, the issue is something like this:

1. When window gets restored, it contains client area only
2. Windows tries to give some non-client area to the window
3. In WM_NCCALCSIZE client area grows to contain non-client area

So, like this window grows a little bit each time I maximize/restore it.
I need to remove non-client area to paint custom form frame with DWM.
I can't simply set window border style to none as then DWM will not paint the window caption and borders.

Please, help to solve the issue and happily have a custom window frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a bug in Windows Forms and there's a workaround. In function `Form.SizeFromClientSize(int, int)` the `AdjustWindowRectEx` function is used to translate the size and it always uses the default measurements and can't be overridden. This function is called from two places:

1. `RestoreWindowBoundsIfNecessary` in WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED window message handler
2. `SetClientSizeCore`

The workaround is the following:

- Override CreateParams in the Form:

  ```
  private bool createParamsHack;

  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
      get
      {
          CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
          // Remove styles that affect the border size
          if (createParamsHack)
              cp.Style &= ~(int)(WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_THICKFRAME);
          return cp;
      }
  }
  ```
- Override WndProc and insert the following code to handle WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:

  ```
      if (m.Msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED)
      {
          createParamsHack = true;
          base.WndProc(ref m);
          createParamsHack = false;
      }
  ```
- Override SetClientSizeCore:

  ```
  protected override void SetClientSizeCore(int x, int y)
  {
      createParamsHack = true;
      base.SetClientSizeCore(x, y);
      createParamsHack = false;
  }
  ```

It may also be good idea to override `SizeFromClientSize(Size)` to return the correct measurements, but it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that soon and tell if it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry for delay with this answer. I tried your suggestion with overriding `CreateParams` and it helped! Also, I tried overriding method 'Form.SizeFromClientSize(Size)' to just return the client size, that is passed to method as an argument. But that didn't help.